# Read a list and print the element that is not repeated

Tags: python

The Following code complies properly for small lists and Timed out error for large sets.

```
li=list(input());
se=set(li);
for i in se:
    count=0
    for j in li:
        if(j==i):
            count=count+1
    if(count==1):
        print(i)
```

[image: Success]

[image: Timed out]

"Success" data set

```
1 2 3 6 5 4 4 2 5 3 6 1 6 5 3 2 4 1 2 5 1 4 3 6 8 4 3 1 5 6 2
```

Expected result

```
8
```

Comment: Please post sample input as text.

Comment: If you don't want to use the [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html?highlight=multiset#collections.Counter) class, I suggest you sort the list and then loop through looking for single entries.

Comment: @Joffan, no need to sort the list. That has terrible time complexity.

Comment: @Kapocsi sorting would be worse than using a Counter, as I say, but probably not a lot worse. Effectively you need to access the Counter index `n` times as you build it, so naively could be quite close to `n log n` (hashing would probably show some benefit).

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter
li=list(input())
cnt = Counter(li)
ans = []

for i in cnt:
    if cnt[i] == 1:
        ans.append(i)

print(*ans)
```

To find the occurrences of an element in a collection, you can use collections.Counter.

Also, your code's time complexity was exceeding o(n^2), that is why the time out was happening.

Comment: `ans =  [v for v,c in cnt.items() if c == 1]` for list comprehension enthusiasts.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is by using bit manipulation

```
def getSingle(arr, n):
    ones = 0
    twos = 0
     
    for i in range(n):
        # one & arr[i]" gives the bits that
        # are there in both 'ones' and new
        # element from arr[]. We add these
        # bits to 'twos' using bitwise OR
        twos = twos | (ones & arr[i])
         
        # one & arr[i]" gives the bits that
        # are there in both 'ones' and new
        # element from arr[]. We add these
        # bits to 'twos' using bitwise OR
        ones = ones ^ arr[i]
         
        # The common bits are those bits
        # which appear third time. So these
        # bits should not be there in both
        # 'ones' and 'twos'. common_bit_mask
        # contains all these bits as 0, so
        # that the bits can be removed from
        # 'ones' and 'twos'
        common_bit_mask = ~(ones & twos)
         
        # Remove common bits (the bits that
        # appear third time) from 'ones'
        ones &= common_bit_mask
         
        # Remove common bits (the bits that
        # appear third time) from 'twos'
        twos &= common_bit_mask
    return ones
```